# Extracting links from HTML

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing

I am trying to extract links from HTML. I am using the following regular expression

```
href=\"([^\"]*)\"
```

Which is extracting unnecessary links. How can I write a regular expression to extract only links with class="l" like

```
<a href="http://users.elite.net/runner/jennifers/hello.htm" class="l">
<a href="http://www.hellodesign.com/" class="l">
<a href="http://www.ipl.org/div/hello/" class="l">
```

Comment: I'll post the obligatory [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/960195) to a very famous answer that discourages parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: The coincidence is that I'm currently wearing a [shirt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition) with an extract of that epic post in the shape of a unicorn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regex is unnecessarily overcomplicated. Regex is the wrong tool for the job. Just use a normal HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It allows you to select HTML elements by normal [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = document.select("a.l"); // Select all <a class="l"> elements.

for (Element link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
}
```

Comment: how to import jsoup into my JSP

Comment: Just drop the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder the usual way to let it participate in the classpath. By the way, Java code [belongs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) in a Java class (like a servlet), not in a JSP file.

Comment: i cannot import jsoup into my JSP it is returing me cannot find symbol for Document,Elements...

Comment: That will indeed happen when it isn't in the runtime classpath. As said, drop the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` the usual way. Then you can import it in your JSP file (or easier, Java class) the usual way as for every other class.

Comment: can you please give me the code for importing i am trying to import like this : <%@page import="org.jsoup.Jsoup"%> it is returing error at org

Comment: That line looks fine. What IDE are you using and what error exactly did you get at org? Can you import it in a normal Java class in the same project?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.0, error: package org.jsoup does not exists, yes i can import normal java class in this project.

Comment: Can you run the JSP file? Just ignore the error and run it. Probably Netbeans is just being a jerk. If running also fails, then the JAR is not in the `/WEB-INF/lib` at all.

Comment: what should be the file name of jar file

Comment: Uh, just the one which you can download from the vendor's homepage. You should already have it, otherwise you wouldn't be able to import it in a normal Java class. You confirmed that this worked.

Comment: actually the WEB-INF did not have lib folder, i created it copied that jar file from vendor's homepage...yet it is not working....

Comment: hey successfully imported jsoup, it is executing fine, but i cannot get any output...

Comment: hello balusC are you there...??

Comment: yes thank you very much, but can help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807186/jsoup-links-extraction

Comment: You already have the answer. You forgot to specify the protocol, so the URL is not an URL at all.

Comment: your code is working to extract links from all website, but it is not working with google and aol. i need to extract links from say :http://www.google.com/search?q=mysearchkeyword

Comment: even after im specifying the protocol...only google and aol are not working, same is working with yahoo, bing and ask....

Comment: my project is to implement a metasearch engine....i am able to extract links from yahoo, bing and ask...but same does not work with google and aol...what may be the reason..??

Comment: hello balusC i need to include two elements variable in for loop, how to do it....ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816605/jsoup-multi-element-output