# Jsoup links extraction

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup

hello guys I am trying to extract all the anchor links from aol but it is not working. The same code is working with yahoo bing. The question is what would be the problem

```
Document document5 = Jsoup.connect("www.aol.com").get();
Elements links5 = document5.select("a");

for (Element link5 : links5) {
    out.println(link5.attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the comments on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780852/extracting-links-from-html/9780910#comment12491047_9780910):

> *even after im specifying the protocol...only google and aol are not working, same is working with yahoo, bing and ask.... my project is to implement a metasearch engine....i am able to extract links from yahoo, bing and ask...but same does not work with google and aol...what may be the reason..??*

They've blocked your request because you're acting as a robot/leecher which may violate their terms of service. Their websites are very frequently requested and they don't want to unnecessarily waste their bandwidth to robots/leechers which actually only need a small part of the response.

Use their public web service APIs instead of parsing the HTML of the entire website. For Google, that's for example "[Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)". Other search engine providers offer similar web services. Note that those web services doesn't return bloated HTML, but compact JSON or XML data which is much easier to parse/extract using JSON/XML parsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate the protocol:

```
Document document5 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.aol.com/").get();
```

Comment: it is working when it is given with normal link but its not working with this link : http://search.aol.com/aol/search?q=hello

Answer (score 0):

Your user agent might be missing. Add a user agent:

```
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36";
Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();
```