# jsoup multi element output

Tags: java, javascript, jsoup

hello guys i am try to print the output of two element data simultaneously

```
Document document2 = Jsoup.parse(webPage2);
Document document22 = Jsoup.parse(webPage2);
Elements links2 = document2.select("a.yschttl");
Elements links22 = document22.select("div.abstr");
```

can we include both a.yschttl and div.abstr or...

```
for (Element link2 : links2) {
out.println(link2);
}
```

can we include two say links2 and links22 in same for loop...
or how to achive it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to select both at the same time, you can do something like this:

```
for (Element link : document.select("a.yschttl, div.abstr") {
    out.println(link);
}
```

If you are trying to make two selections and outputting those values in tandem, you will have to do something like @vacuum suggests, but being careful of the lengths of the lists.

A side note, you don't have to parse the document twice to make two selections.  You can parse once and select twice.

Comment: hey thank you it worked exactly what i intended to do...but i got a problem in some cases div.abstr is empty, so how do i print some text rather than left it empty....

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < links2.size(); i++) {
   out.println(links2.get(i));
   out.println(links22.get(i));
}
```

But in this case you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if size of `links22` higher than size of `links2`.

What do you want to achieve?